# 'git status' yields different results in git bash (Windows 10) an WSL2 bash

Tags: bash, git

I work on Windows 10 with WSL2. I initialized a git repo in git bash (Windows) and everything works fine (commit, push etc.).

```
git status     # on Windows, git bash
```

[image]

When I switch to WSL2 and have a look at the same status of the same repo (drive mounted in WSL), I find that all files are untracked (WSL2 bash).

```
git status     # same repo in WSL2 bash
```

[image]

**My Questions:**

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there a way to avoid this and achieve consistency across both OS (i.e. without cloning into a separate repo in WSL)?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. Images are only good to show something non-textual.

Answer (score 0):

you might find some answers [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/184)

TLDR : `git config --global core.autocrlf true`

Comment: The link points to this question. Please fix it.